# Yii2 Rest API Location

Tags: php, yii2

I needed to know which folder is more suitable to host my **Rest API in Yii2 template advanced**, **backend** or **frontend**.
I also saw some examples where developers **created a new directory**, called it "api" and programmed the API from there, but I don't find much information by developing from this method.
If you know the most correct way to do it, I would appreciate if you could explain me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That totally depends on your requirements if it is going to be a complete full app or just a single controller with a few actions or a single `ActiveController`.

But a good way is to keep things separate just like you are using the `advance-app` and you have the `backend` and `frontend` folders so that you can differentiate the code base, and keep the code in their concerned folders, those folders are actually 2 separate `applications` running separately with their own separate configurations i.e `backend/config/*` and `frontend/config/*`, and can share some common configurations like database and others from the `common/config/*`. Same like that you can create a separate application/folder where you can have all the code base and configurations related to api you are going to build.

You can find a very good reference for adding more apps into your existing application by Yii [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-adding-more-apps.md) on GITHUB which will clear your concept about how to add more apps.

Then you can go to this article by [Budi Irawan's Tech Blog](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/) which uses the `advance-app` to add a new application for the API. You will find the directory structure with example models and controllers along with testing them with POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0):

`Backend` and `frontend` are also just a folder in the `Yii2 advance app` with just `namespace` different, they are different for our understanding, it is not necessary that you use `backend` for backend purpose only.

So for the `API`, you can use any of these folders, but it is always recommended to put thing separately like we put backend thing in `backend` folder and frontend things in `frontend` folder.

It's totally up to you and your coding style.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer putting Rest API into a separate module, for instance into "common\modules\api". that way i can "mount" the api in **backend or frontend** via **configuration**. Also, nice urls are automatically provided, like `/api/<controller>/<action>` (where `api` is the name of your module).
One more thing to consider is how to update your api. in case of modules everything is well organized. you could start with "v1" and put your controllers in here, and move up to "v2" with a different set of controllers. so your first api endpoint would read `/v1/users`, later on you can additionally provide `/v2/users`.

more about modules [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-modules)

read "URL Rules" [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing)